# How to retrieve the chosen order attribute on category page in magento?

Tags: magento

Been googling for a while now, but couldn't find a solution for this - i think - kinda trivial question. I'd like to retrieve the attribute by which a product catalog is ordered. I don't want to be able to order the category page by a custom attribute, just want to now by which attribute it is sorted.

Actually I have three possibilities "position", "name" & "price. I would like to do something with the first 3 products, but only if the category catalog is ordered by position.

Anyone have an idea how I can achieve this value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->getCurrentOrder();
?>
```

Comment: Superb!

That line was just what I needed :) Works like a charm.

Thanks!